# Why red instead of grey in review queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review

[image: Red]

This is the first time I'm seeing a red colour beside a queue. What's its significance?

I did around 5 "First Questions" review and that I've done before with a grey symbol too. (1 was a test but again that was with grey symbol too before).

Comment: Related posts on [meta.se]: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The red dot means that there are 'many' items to review in that queue, it is there to encourage reviewing. The gray dot means that there are items to review.

The precise meaning of 'many' depends on the queue.

For more details see the link provided by Martin [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly)

Comment: What you say is correct but I think sometimes despite many reviews, there is a grey dot sometimes instead of red one as it should be but that's something of a different matter unrelated to this one so thank you for your answer.

Comment: See also: [What is the threshold for the review-needed indicator (the red circle) in the First Questions and First Answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381363).